# Does TLS 1.3 mitigate the BREACH vulnerability?

Tags: tls, threat-mitigation, side-channel, compression, breach

[Section 5.4 of the TLS 1.3 specification describes record padding.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-5.4)

One of the mitigations for [BREACH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BREACH) is to add random padding.

Therefore, I'm wondering:

1. Does TLS 1.3 require *random* record padding? I'm also unclear on if this padding is optional or required, and if it is always random.
2. If TLS 1.3 random record padding is done, am I correct in thinking that it does mitigate BREACH?

Assuming both of those questions are answered affirmatively, I believe that would mean that any site that uses TLS 1.3 (and supports no earlier version of SSL/TLS) would not be vulnerable to BREACH.

Answer (score 3):

This [article](https://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/tls-vulnerabilities-attacks-final-part/), under **BREACH** sums it up pretty well.

> BREACH targets `HTTP` compression, not `TLS` compression

With that said, the random record padding can be done on a higher level of encapsulation and not on the `TLS` record itself. You do not want to be obscuring the length of the record but the whole response.

Here are the preventive measures mentioned in the [post above](https://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/tls-vulnerabilities-attacks-final-part/),

- Disable `HTTP` compression
- Separate secrets from user input (these secrets can be taken as a CSRF token)
- Randomize secrets per request
- Mask secrets (effectively randomizing by `XORing` with a random secret per request)
- Protect pages against CSRF
- Hide the length (by adding random numbers of bytes to responses)
- Limit the rate of requests

Comment: Honestly, just disabling HTTP compression on sites containing a secret is enough. Static assets or sites without user-supplied data can be sent compressed.

Answer (score 1):

> Does TLS 1.3 require random record padding?

[RFC 8446 - The Transport Layer Security (TLS) Protocol Version 1.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#section-5.4) says this is not required:

> implementations MAY choose to pad.

In practice, padding doesn't seem to be used much. I checked message size with Wireshark while submitting a form to a TLS 1.3 site via Chrome, and the size of the encrypted message corresponds to the size of the plaintext message.

So padding is not used in practice, and thus not mitigates BREACH.

> If TLS 1.3 random record padding is done, am I correct in thinking that it does mitigate BREACH?

It doesn't make it impossible in theory, but perhaps impossible in practice. In general it is possible to average out the padding by performing sufficiently many requests. If the padding is between 0 and 10 bytes, but 5 bytes on average, an attacker can perform many requests and subtract 5 to get the correct original size.